# Installing Bouncy Castle API on Mac OS

Tags: java, api, bouncycastle

I'm trying to install bouncy castle API on my mac and I need to copy the libraries into the JRE subfolder (I assume it would be /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home on mac). I have installed JDK V8 and restarted my machine. I am following the instructions [here](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/08/22/how-to-use-bouncy-castle-cryptographic-api-in-netbeans-or-eclipse-for-java-jse-projects/) (solution 1)

How can I access the Frameworks folder, copy bouncy castle into it, and modify the java.security file? Or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I would not copy any libraries, including the bouncycastle libraries, into the JRE folders. Instead, copy it into a user folder, like ~/lib or something similar.

Comment: But I have to do it to configure the Java Runtime for bouncy castle.

Comment: Yes, but almost always the correct way is to put the libraries someplace in a user directory and make sure the jars you need are on the classpath. Every java tool and configuration system I'm aware of has an ability to add directories and jars to the classpath.